# If $U \subset M_{n,k}(\mathbb{R})$ is open, and $g \in GL_k(\mathbb{R})$, then how to show that $Ug$ is open?

Tags: general-topology, grassmannian

This question is from my course of smooth manifolds.

Let $G(k,n)$ denote $\{k\text{-dimensional vector space in } \mathbb{R}^n\}$, 
which is equal to $\{n \times k \text{ matrix of rank }= k\} \big/ \sim$

where $A \sim B \iff  \exists g \in GL_k(\mathbb{R}) ~\text{such that} ~B = Ag$.

I want to show that the equivalent relation $\sim$ is open, 
which means that the canonical (projection) map is open.

**The below is my trial :**

Let $F(k,n)$ denote $\{n \times k \text{ matrix of rank }= k\}$, 
and $\pi$ denote the canonical (projection) map derived from $\sim$.

Assume that $U$ is open in $F(k,n)$.

To show that $\sim$ is open, it is enough to show that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$ is open in $F(k,n)$.

$$\pi^{-1}(\pi(U)) = \{Ag : A \in U, ~ g \in GL_k(\mathbb{R})\} 
= \bigcup_{g \in GL_k(\mathbb{R})} Ug .$$

Thus if $Ug$ is open for all $g \in GL_k(\mathbb{R})$, then $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$ is open, 
and so I obtain the fact that $\sim$ is open.

**I tried to prove it directly.**

For any $A \in Ug$, we know $Ag^{-1} \in U$. Because $U$ is open, 
there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $B_\epsilon(Ag^{-1}) \subset U$.

Hence $B_\epsilon(Ag^{-1})g \subset Ug$, and we know $A \in B_\epsilon(Ag^{-1})g$.

Thus if we can find $\delta > 0$ satisfying $B_\delta(A) \subset B_\epsilon(Ag^{-1})g$, 
then we can conclude that $Ug$ is open.

However, I'm stuck to proceed.

I would really appreciate to concern and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $g: M_{n, k}(\mathbb R) \to M_{n, k}(\mathbb R)$ given by $A \mapsto Ag$ is continuous; you know the rules of matrix multiplication, the entries of $Ag$ end up being polynomials in the entries of $A$, polynomials are continuous.

Moreover, it has a continuous inverse $A \mapsto A g^{-1}$, so it is a homeomorphism. Homeomorphisms are open maps, so $Ug$ is open.